# NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, 20.10

I installed Ubuntu 20.10, My PC is very slow when I was on Ubuntu 20.04 it's fine, When searching the internet I found a solution to install Nvidia drivers and I did as [follow](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/), I installed Nvidia `nvidia-driver-455`

And when I try verifying as in the screenshot

[image]

```
chawki@chawki-Aspire-V5-471:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Comment: What nvidia hardware model do you have.  Not all of them can use the latest driver.  How did you install the 455 driver?  From the GUI Software and Updates/Additional Drivers, did you select the "tested recommended" one?

Comment: In addition to ubfan1 questions you should add the output of `lscpi` to your question by using the **edit** link below it...

Comment: @ubfan1 I don't find anything to install on "Software and Updates/Additional Drivers", Then I use the terminal to install the the `nvidia-driver-455`, And I try also installing `nvidia-driver-390` but same problem.

Comment: You might have to "enable propietary drivers" in order to see those in the Software Center.

Comment: how to "enable proprietary drivers"?

Comment: Apparently you don't have any Nvidia hardware.  If that's really the case, installing the drivers helps nothing. The only VGA controller I see in your posted list is for Intel.

Comment: OMG, I don't realize it, And is there any other reason why is my PC is slow?

Comment: Why are you upgrading to 20.10 when 20.04 worked fine for you?  You do realize that with 20.04 you get support for up to 5 years on it where 20.10 you  will have to upgrade in < 9 months.